# Is there an onCloseWindowEvent() in TornadoFX?

Tags: tornadofx

I want to write some information in console and to show a confirmation dialog (like a "Are You sure to close this window?"), when I click on [X].

I know how to do it for Swing components, but I found no information for TornadoFX (I'm new in kotlin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can configure the `onCloseRequest` callback for the current window and consume the close event. Then you can ask your own question and hide the window when you want:

```
override fun onDock() {
    currentWindow?.setOnCloseRequest {
        it.consume()
        confirm("Really close?", "Do you want to close") {
            currentWindow?.hide()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, that is what I want. Thank you!

Comment: I have one more question. As I understood this override is may be writed only in main `View`. So, if I want to use a properties from a different `ViewModel`, then I should use them only in this `onCloseRequest `, am I right?

Comment: Actually, you can override App#start() and configure the setOnCloseRequest on the stage there. You can inject any model even in the App subclass.